# No puedo acceder a la carpeta storage link por FTP

Tags: laravel

Tengo una app en producción, en la cual tengo que cargar de forma masiva muchas imágenes a la carpeta storage que se crea al ejecutar el comando storage:link. Estoy tratando de subir todas las imágenes por FTP y no puedo acceder al contenido de la carpeta.

He tratado también mover las imágenes por consola pero me dice lo mismo.

Hay alguna forma de hacer esto?

Comment: Entonces, se te creo la carpeta storage? Y que es lo que dice...que error sale?

Comment: @JuanRivera  Si, la carpeta esta ahí. Solo me dice que es inaccesible. Y si lo intento por consola dice que no se encontró el directorio.